# How to view axis label and values in d3 js bar chart?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, bar-chart

### Hi everyone i have been following some youtube tutorials on making bar charts in D3.js and i seemed to have goofed up a few things as my output went haywire

*Here is my html file*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>My Data Record</title>

    <!-- CSS stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <!-- D3.js CDN source -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Title -->
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Monthly Dispensed Amount</h1>

    <!-- Your D3 code for bar graph -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gdpBarGraph.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

*and here is my javascript file*

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 100, left:50},
    width = 700 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
      .attr ({
        "width": width + margin.right + margin.left,
        "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom
      })
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");


// defining  x and y scales
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0,width], 0.2, 0.2);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

// defining x axis and y axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");

d3.csv("newcashdata.csv", function(error,data) {
  if(error) console.log("Error: data could  not be loaded!");

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = d.date;
    d.amount = +d.amount;       
    console.log(d.amount);   
  });

  // sort the values to show at which date the cash collection was the highest
  data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.amount - a.amount;
  });

  // Specify the domains of the x and y scales
  xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }) );
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.amount; } ) ]);

  svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("height", 0)
    .attr("y", height)
    .transition().duration(3000)
    .delay( function(d,i) { return i * 200; })

    .attr({
      "x": function(d) { return xScale(d.date); },
      "y": function(d) { return yScale(d.amount); },
      "width": xScale.rangeBand(),
      "height": function(d) { return  height - yScale(d.amount); }
    })
    .style("fill", function(d,i) { return 'rgb(20, 20, ' + ((i * 30) + 100) + ')'});


        svg.selectAll('text')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('text')



            .text(function(d){
                return d.amount;
            })
            .attr({
                "x": function(d){ return xScale(d.date) +  xScale.rangeBand()/2; },
                "y": function(d){ return yScale(d.amount)+ 12; },
                "font-family": 'sans-serif',
                "font-size": '13px',
                "font-weight": 'bold',
                "fill": 'white',
                "text-anchor": 'middle'
            });

    // Drawing x axis and positioning the label
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-60)" )
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", "10px"); 


    // Drawing  y Axis and positioning the label
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", -height/2)
        .attr("dy", "-2em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Amount Dispensed");
});
```

*and lastly my stylesheet:*

```
svg {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text{
    font: Times;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

*here's what i am getting as output:*
[image]

*as its evident i made a mess out of my Y axis label "Amount Dispensed" and i can't think of a way to change that is it because of my font size in stylesheet or some other mistake in my code, any help will be highly appreciated.*

### edit: here is my csv file

[image]

*here is the output after right axis changes*
*The y axis label did came back however the numbers on individual bars seem to be too big to depict is there a way to shorten them for isntance say 950000 to 950K and likewise*
[image]

Comment: Try increasing your left margin, 75 will probably do it.

Comment: also the values on the y axis are not entirely visible is there a way to show them too?

Comment: @pmkro tried 75 no change

Comment: @pmkro the right margin changed did the needful but now i am struck with inconsistent numbers on thin lines

Comment: What do you mean "inconsistent numbers on thin lines"? It looks find to me. Also [I created this](https://jsfiddle.net/mmdz87ey/). Slightly moved where the y label is placed, data is all dummy data.

Comment: @pmkro I mean is there a way to make the numbers on bars appear as eg... 950000 as 950k so that it looks more presentable

Comment: Yep [See documentation here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_formatPrefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a full fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se1dmxa8/)

I increased your `margin.left` to 75 from 50. I also modified your yAxis creation to fix scale number formatting the `s` [will change numbers into their corresponding prefix](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_formatPrefix) (7000 to 7k etc.)

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
```

The data I used was just randomly created as the issues were just in axis formatting.

I also moved over the label you added to the yAxis from `y: -2em` to `y: -3em`

Comment: I tried yours solution but the result is stipp the same on my data

Comment: I tried your solution but is didn't had any effect in my output its still the same as before

Comment: My modifications should not depend on the data fed in. What output is the same?

Comment: By same output I mean that the resulting bar chart display is still the same when I tried the tickFormat()  method the entire values on y axis are still there also , I wanted to display 950k on the individual bars instead of the current 9500000 that are too big on a small bar size

Comment: There must be something with your implementation. .tickformat(d3.format("s")) should do it.

Comment: that worked but how can I get the same 700k,900k etc on each bars in the chart instead of values

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm have accepted your answer as it fulfilled my requirements